# Embed Approval Workflow into InfoPath Form?

Tags: workflow, infopath

I would like to find out whether its possible to embed approval workflow status 'approved' into an InfoPath form - filled in and completed on SharePoint 2013.

We are able to approve workflows and show the approval status in the document library list however we want this detail to show within the actual xml form document.

Any assistance would be appreciated.